# how can i launch my app or an activity on notification received when app is in background or killed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform

I have a requirement for my app. I have to launch my app when I received a Notification (specific notification type) when my app is in background or killed state. I didn't find any solution for background. I'm using FCM for notifications.

Actually my app support calling functionality from web side to mobile and when admin initiate call then I received a FCM push notification. when my app is foreground than it's work fine but when it is in background, than I received notification but for launch app I have to click on notification. but I need to launch app immediately. Have any one have any solution?

Comment: I strongly suggest not trying to immediately launch your app upon receipt of a message.  This is disruptive to the user experience.  Imagine if all apps simply forced themselves to launch just because a message was received - that would be **very** undesirable chaos as all apps simply message themselves to get attention.

Comment: i think its very hard after android improved their security. we cannot run app like that we can open app when onMessageReceived() method it will work some time than it will automatically destroy. you can try using package whitelisted if it's work.

Comment: there are genuine need to to immediately launch the app when received push notification, like when user received a call in app

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use your app server and FCM server API: Set the data key only. Can be either collapsible or non-collapsible.**

If you are sending the notification from console, then use the particular key to send the notification from the Advanced Option features.

```
   if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
     // Call your NotificationActivity here..
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: it will work when click on notification. it's working but i need auto launch my app when received the notification.